# windows xps document writer can not print tiff files windows 7 64

Tags: windows-7, xps

Have to print .tiff files for bank app, but under advanced options in XPS document printer there is no .tiff format available.
Also cannot install windows document image writer on this os.
OS Windows 7 Home premium. 
Please advise urgently

Comment: Can you use the Paint application included with the OS?

Comment: The short answer is that XPS is not TIFF, and the XPS printer does not create TIFFs, no matter where in the settings you go.

Answer (score 1):

XPS is Microsoft's answer (sort of) to PDF so is not the same as TIFF.

There are two common ways of creating TIFF's via print.

If you have the Microsoft FAX printer driver installed, choose that but tick the box that says "Print to File" before clicking on print.

If you have Microsoft Office Document Imaging installed (part of the MS Office suite), I think you can use that as well.

Other alternatives are installing the ImageMagick batch tools which can convert from PDF to TIFF (and do loads of other stuff too). Or use a capable image editor such as the GIMP

Answer (score 1):

If the original documents are PDFs you can use [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/). Among its many execellent features, it can read and write a huge number of formats.

If the documents are not PDFs, you can use something like the [Print to TIFF](http://code-industry.net/print-to-tiff.php) driver. It acts like a printer driver, but creates TIFFs instead. I have not used it, so I do not know how well it will work.

You could also print to PDF first, and then use IrfanView to create the TIFF from it.

And of course, you can always use the PrtScn key (or the Win 7 Snipping Tool, or a 3rd party screengrab application) to copy the screen contents, paste that into Paint or IrfanView, and save it as a TIFF.